# discord bot from where you can read and send messages at same time

Tags: python, multithreading, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a code where I can read messages from people in the console but can also send messages from the console at the same time.

I tried:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  channel = message.channel
  content = message.content
  user = message.author

  talk = input('>')
  await channel.send(talk)
  print(f'{user} - {content}')
```

This would until a while because it have to take what I wanted to say before it could display what others were saying.

I did some searching online and I have to use multithreading so I tried this:

```
  @client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    talk = input('>')
    await channel.send(talk)
    def read(message):
        content = message.content
        user = message.author
        print(f'{user} - {content}')

    threadObj = threading.Thread(target=read(message))
    threadObj.start()
```

But it doesn't work either can someone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're doing that in `on_message`, so you'll only be able to send one of those. In fact, the `input` is the one thing that blocks. As a side effect, as people send more messages, you can end up with thousands of threads (not good). You'll have to get the *input* from another thread (running continuously).

Comment: Thanks @EricJin I don't really understand what you mean, can your write an example?

Comment: So you are trying to make a Live Console that sends a message to a certain channel? Or globally?

Comment: @HiigariYoshinova I programmed mine for channel but global would also work